# Checking if certain data is already a database and if so update the data

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a code that send to a database some information that I write while I run the code into a database and now I need to check if the data that I am inserting into the database is already there and if so I must update it. I will leave my code below so it can me more easy for you to help. If you need more code feel free to ask I will provide you.

```
try
{
 conn.Open();
 string sqlQuery = @"INSERT INTO UXMenu(TransDocument, TransSerial, TransDocNumber, PartyName, PartyLocalityID, TotalAmount, ShipToPostalCode, Estado , IDZona ,Bonus,NumFac) VALUES (@transdocument, @transserial, @transdocnumber, @partyname, @partylocal, @totalamount, @shiptocode, @estado ,@IDZona ,@Bonus,@NumFac)";
 SqlCommand SQLcm = new SqlCommand();
 SQLcm.Connection = conn;
 SQLcm.CommandText = sqlQuery;
 SQLcm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 SQLcm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transdocument", transdocument);
 SQLcm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transserial", transserial);
 SQLcm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transdocnumber", transaction.TransDocNumber);
 SQLcm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@partyname", nomecli);
 SQLcm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@partylocal", locality);
 SQLcm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalamount", transaction.TotalAmount);
 SQLcm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shiptocode", shipto);
 SQLcm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado", estado);
 SQLcm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDZona", "0");
 SQLcm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bonus", "0");
 SQLcm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumFac", "0"); 
 SQLcm.ExecuteNonQuery();
 MessageBox.Show("inseriu dados");
 conn.Close();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
  throw ex;
 }
}
```

UPDATE 1:

This is how I create the table:

```
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConecçãoDB))
 {
  conn.Open();
  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("IF OBJECT_ID('UXMenu', 'U') IS NULL CREATE TABLE UXMenu(TransDocument varchar(5), TransSerial varchar(5), TransDocNumber float  PRIMARY KEY, PartyName varchar(60), PartyLocalityID varchar(5), TotalAmount varchar(25), ShipToPostalCode varchar(35), Estado int, IDZona varchar(15),Bonus varchar(15),NumFac varchar(15));", conn);
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  MessageBox.Show("tabela criada menu");
  conn.Close();
```

Comment: Personally, I find a good solution to use a stored procedure, where you check whether the row with a key exists and perform `UPDATE` or `INSERT` according to it.

Comment: Personally, I like having Change-History. So I would add a timestamp and insert only with actual timestamp. When Selecting, filter for newest timestamp for each entry (or create view accordingly). That makes for an easy "undo" and "who changed what and when".

Comment: Personally, I'd write `AddOrUpdate` method containing a complicated check using primary key to check if *local* database already has the item and to either insert or update.

Comment: Is this SQL Server?

Comment: most DBMS allow you to put constraints into place that enforce anti duplicate rules ... what about: place such a constraint ... try to insert, and if it fails because of a constraint, handle the update?

Comment: @RadimBača can you give me aexample please?

Comment: @AshleyPillay yes

Comment: @JosueFigueiredo how do you decide that the data are already there? In other words, what is the key of the table?

Comment: I updated the question with some code

Comment: Have a look at `MERGE` construction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not posted your DB schema & sample data, so I cannot give you a query to execute.

However, what you want to do can be achieved in SQL Server via the `MERGE` statement.

This was added in SQL Server 2008 to accomodate `UPSERT` statments which are also very common but had no language support & had to be performed in 2 steps.

`MERGE` lets you achieve a `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, or `DELETE` in a target table based on the results of a join with a source table.

The documentation can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql

Here's a basic example with your table schema.

Run it twice. First run will do an `INSERT`, second run will do the `UPDATE`

```
IF OBJECT_ID('UXMenu', 'U') IS NULL CREATE TABLE UXMenu(TransDocument varchar(5), TransSerial varchar(5), TransDocNumber float  PRIMARY KEY, PartyName varchar(60), PartyLocalityID varchar(5), TotalAmount varchar(25), ShipToPostalCode varchar(35), Estado int, IDZona varchar(15),Bonus varchar(15),NumFac varchar(15));

DECLARE @TargetTransDocNumber float=1;

SELECT * FROM UXMenu;

MERGE UXMenu AS target
USING 
(
    SELECT @TargetTransDocNumber as TransDocNumber
) AS source
ON (target.TransDocNumber = source.TransDocNumber)  
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT(TransDocument, TransSerial, TransDocNumber, PartyName, PartyLocalityID, TotalAmount, ShipToPostalCode, Estado, IDZona, Bonus, NumFac)
    VALUES('doc1', 'ser1', @TargetTransDocNumber, 'par1', 'ploc1', 'totamt1', 'postal1', 1, 'zon1', 'bon1', 'fac1')
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
        target.TransDocument = 'doc2',
        target.TransSerial='ser2',
        target.PartyName='par2',
        target.PartyLocalityID='ploc2',
        target.TotalAmount='totamt2',
        target.ShipToPostalCode='postal2',
        target.Estado=2,
        target.IDZona='zon2',
        target.Bonus='bon2',
        target.NumFac='fac2';

SELECT * FROM UXMenu;
```